# Is there any way to get text from the console of another application?

Tags: c++, console-application

I have a third party console application in term as "reg.exe". When I run it, it shows me a text message. I want to use this string in my application.
How do I get this string?

I want to use [CreatProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/ProcThread/creating-processes) to execute "reg.exe",

```
CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

Then use

```
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
```

to wait it to be finished.

Comment: How you execute reg.exe isn't the question. The question is how to grab the text from a window reg.exe displays.

Comment: @CareyGregory: It does matter. If it's a console application, then you should be able to invoke it and hook its standard output directly to your application. But that depends on creating it properly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output